# Does this method that changes an instance variable belong in my Rails controller or model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a basic "best practice" question about controllers and instance variables.

Say you have an instance variable in anew or update action in a controller, is it ok to modify that instance variable via a private method in the controller?  Or should the method exist in the model?

e.g. in this example below, I need to loop through the attributes of an instance variable, and add or remove something.  For example, if I am using nested attributes 3 layers deep and have to remove certain attributes, change them and then add them back in.  I know this may seem strange, but assume it is necessary.

```
def new
  @some_thing = SomeThing.new(:some_params)
  do_something_to_inst_var # method call
  @some_thing.save
end

private

def do_something_to_inst_var
  @some_thing.addresses.each do |address|
    # modify it in some  way
  end
end
```

Or is this bad practice?  Should this be a method in the model and should be called like:

```
@some_thing.do_something_to_inst_var
```

OR

should we explicitly pass the instance variable to the method like:

```
def new
  @some_thing = SomeThing.new(:some_params)
  do_something_to_inst_var(@some_thing) # method call
  @some_thing.save
end

private

def do_something_to_inst_var(some_thing)
  some_thing.addresses.each do |addresses|
    # modify it in some way
  end
end
```

I'm looking for some clarity here, with an example if possible.  I'm still learning and trying to improve and I didn't find an answer by searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails applications should have ["thin controllers" and "fat models"](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model) for a couple of reasons:

- Each object should handle only its own responsibilities. A controller should just be about connecting the web, the the model and the view, which thanks to Rails doesn't take much code. If a controller method refers repeatedly to methods of the same model, it's incorrectly taking on model responsibilities; we say that it's not [cohesive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) or that it has ["Feature Envy"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FeatureEnvySmell). It is more likely that if the model changes the controller will have to change in parallel.
- It's easier to test models than to test controllers.

Fix it by writing a method in the model that does the model-specific work and call it in the controller (your second option). (Eventually your model will get too fat and you'll have to break it up too, but that's another story.) For example:

```
class SomeThingsController
  def new
    @some_thing = SomeThing.new(:some_params)
    @some_thing.do_something # method call
    @some_thing.save
  end
end

class SomeThing
  def do_something
    addresses.each do |address|
      # modify it in some  way
    end
  end
end
```

Regarding instance variables.

- Define them only if necessary. Presumably the one in your example is needed for the view.
- Assuming an instance variable is justified at all, there's no reason not to refer to it in private methods of the class that contains it. That's what they're for. So your first option (referring directly to the instance variable) is a bit better than your third option (passing it in). But, as discussed above, extracting a model method is better than both of the other two options.

Comment: thanks, would the model method refer to @some_thing? or be self.each etc? could you provide an example based on the code I have given?

Comment: It would just call methods on itself (and you wouldn't even need to say `self.` except for assignments.) I'd add an example to my question, but I just noticed that you're calling `each` on `@some_thing`, which seems odd. You might want to clear that up by editing your question.

Comment: I added an explanation, but lets say I had a company with lots of addresses, and  those addresses had many types of address (mailing, billing etc).  I have to loop through the instance variable and delete and address, modify it, and add it back to the instance var.

Comment: I changed your example code to look more like what you said. See what you think.

Comment: Thanks, looks good. So if Addresses was a class too, and it was a nested attribute for SomeThing.  In the SomeThing class, would I write: self.addresses.each.....

Comment: I think I just answered that in my update to my answer; take a look.

Comment: I did have a look first, and it says addresses.each do, so I assume you don't need self..

Comment: Thanks, but won't 'addresses' be a variable which hasn't been defined anywhere?

Comment: If `SomeThing` `has_many :addresses`, `addresses` would be the association method that returns the `SomeThing`'s `Address`es.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion Modifying `@instance_vars` from private method is okay if your controller is just 100 lines long.

Imagine a scenario where there are 500 LOC in your controller and after a struggle of a couple of hours you found out that the `@intance_var` is being modified by some private method.

---

**Helpful tips**:

- create small private methods with single responsibility
- put `!` at the end of `method_name!` indicating that it modifies something. Specially this is helpful when you see `my_private_method!`, `!` makes you realize that its modifying something.
- lets not put code in controller that do not belong here.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more option:

**In Controller:**

```
def new
  @some_thing = SomeThing.new(:some_params)
  @some_thing_modified = @some_thing.modify_somehow(params)
  @some_thing_modified.save
end
```

**In `SomeThing` Model:**

```
def modify_somehow(params)
  result = self.clone
  # ... modify result ...
  return result
end
```

Because `modify_somehow` is now [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) (assuming you don't do anything in `... modify result ...` part, that makes it impure), what you gain here is [Referential transparency](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254304/what-is-referential-transparency). Main benefit of referential transparency is that you can determine what function/method invocation will do, only by looking at its arguments, and get result of its work only via return value, and not via [side effects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect). This makes your code more predictable, which in turn makes it easier to understand and debug.

There are of course disadvantages: Because you create new object this option can be less performant, it's also more verbose than its alternatives.

Functional programming concepts, like referential transparency, are not very popular in Rails community (probably because of how OO-centric Ruby is). But referential transparency is there if you want it, with its pros and cons.